# I need to fail a build in Visual Studio Online (VSTS) from my gulp linting process

Tags: javascript, gulp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use JShint and output errors and warnings. I want to fail a build on this result. How can I accomplish this using the VSO build process?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a command line task and build by your [private agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) on a local machine which jshint is installed.

For the **Command Line task**, you can use below settings:

**Tool:** `jshint`

**Arguments:** the `.js` file in your repo, such as `gulpfile.js`

[image]

And you will get the same error message as you used JShint directly, such as the error message in VSO build as:

```
jshint gulpfile.js
gulpfile.js: line 9, col 11, Duplicate key 'string'.
gulpfile.js: line 11, col 2, Missing semicolon.
gulpfile.js: line 22, col 36, Missing semicolon.
3 errors
Process completed with exit code 2.
```